# How do I scaffold a project using React/JSX but with Java/Jetty instead of node?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, jetty, niagara-ax

I have a Gradle-controlled back end project already written in Java (to be precise, a Tridium Niagara 4 station). By default, the Niagara framework already provides the Jetty web server used by the application.

I now want to add a front end, and the technology needs to be React, ideally written with JSX syntax. **Based on the above paragraph, it needs to work with the existing Jetty web server rather than Node**.

Another requirement is that the front end code needs to be able to refer to a Tridium data modelling API known as BajaScript (provided as bs.min.js). This library allows references to be made to properties of objects in the running Java application. Version 1 of BajaScript uses Ajax, version 2 uses web sockets.

I included the information about Niagara so that readers are aware of the back end environment I'm working in, but I don't expect responders to know anything specific about it.

My question is this: Any ideas/links/code snippets as to how do I go about scaffolding the front end to suit the existing back end ? Are there any suitable 'templates' or 'starter kits' that would accelerate this for me ?

Answer (score 0):

Niagara 4.x Jetty is embedded. You can develop using Jetty itself without the whole Niagara server, if you're not using Niagara APIs. Why don't you test a simple proof of concept using React/Jetty without Niagara, then test porting it to Niagara? Replying here with your results would help the community.